# exclude documents based on existence of value in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following collection/documents:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "a1b2c3",
        "title": "book title number one",
        "excluded": [1,2]
    },
    {
        "_id": "d4e5f6",
        "title": "book title number two",
        "excluded": [1]
]
```

Let's say the numbers in the excluded-array are userID's. In the first document, user ID 1 and user ID 2 are excluded, so they cannot see this document. The second document can only be seen by user ID 2.

I want to do a query on this collection fetching ALL documents where user ID 2 **IS NOT** in the excluded, so I want to fetch all document user ID 2 can view.

I tried this so far:

```
collection.find({ excluded: { $nin: [2] } }) // does not work
collection.find({ excluded: { $nin: 2 } }) // does not work
collection.find({ excluded: { $ne: [2] } }) // does not work
collection.find({ excluded: { $ne: 2 } }) // does not work
collection.find({ excluded: { $not: { $in: 2 } } }) // does not work
```

So I want to check if 1 value exists in an array in a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection.find({ excluded: { $nin: [2] } })` works fine and give me the second document. Make sure that your Ids are stored as integers as you are making query in integer